# Associate rails api and ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On submitting, my Ember frontend is sending me data like this:

```
{
   "data":{
      "attributes":{
         "title":"asd",
         "description":"asd"
      },
      "relationships":{
         "users":{
            "data":[
               {
                  "type":"users",
                  "id":"1"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "type":"cards"
   }
}
```

Here, I want to associate between a `card` and a `user` when a new `card` is created.

app/controllers/cards_controller.rb

```
def create
  @card = Card.new(card_params)

  if @card.save
    @card.users << User.find(params[:data][:relationships][:users][:data]) if params[:data][:relationships][:users][:data]

    render json: @card
  else
    render json: @card, :status => 422
  end
end

private

def card_params
   params.require(:data).require(:attributes).permit(:title, :description)
end
```

The error in the Rails end is something like this:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Method to_a is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1, as `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from hash. Using this deprecated behavior exposes potential security problems. If you continue to use this method you may be creating a security vulnerability in your app that can be exploited. Instead, consider using one of these documented methods which are not deprecated: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html (called from create at /Applications/AMPPS/www/development/ideast/hub/hub-server/app/controllers/cards_controller.rb:16)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `join' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007f9b5549e380>
Did you mean?  JSON):
```

Repo link: https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/hub-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to customize your Ember adapters to send the correct data format.

However, here's a way I'd probably go about solving the current issue:

**The `user_params` method isn't so clean, I'd probably want to find a cleaner way of handling it.

```
def create
  @card = Card.new(card_params)

  if @card.save
    @card.users << User.find(user_params)

    render json: @card
  else
    render json: @card, :status => 422
  end
end

private

def user_params
   params.require(:data).require(:relationships).require(:users).permit(data: [:id]).require(:data).map(&:values)
end

def card_params
   params.require(:data).require(:attributes).permit(:title, :description)
end
```